# How can I identify which application I have installed for mouse gestures?

Tags: macos, mouse, gesture

My middle mouse button is set to create mouse gestures. I've spent several hours on different occasions trying to understand which app I installed to set up the gestures but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Does anybody know how I could track down a currently active app?
Or, maybe, is anybody able to visually recognize the app from looking at the "gesture track" the app creates? See here:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, is this software you purchased and/or downloaded online? Or, was it bundled with some hardware you purchased? If so, what hardware? Finally, do you remember roughly how long ago you downloaded/installed it?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding!
I just solved the issue when typing my answer to you... The gesture lines are created by the app "Jitouch". 
This was the first thing I tested a few months ago, but apparently, I didn't test properly. I thought it was NOT Jitouch, but it turns out that it was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app that creates this mouse gesture path is called Jitouch.
It creates the gesture path when drawing a gesture with two fingers on the trackpad AND when using the middle mouse button of a classic computer mouse.